# How to show $1+\sqrt2 +\cdots+ \sqrt{2^n}$ is algebraic?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-numbers

How to show that $1+\sqrt2 +\cdots+ \sqrt{2^n}$ is an algebraic?

$x=1+\sqrt2 +\cdots+ \sqrt{2^n}$

$x-1=\sqrt2 +\cdots+ \sqrt{2^n}$

Every other element is an integer so I can move it to the left side. I would like to square both sides, move integer elements to the left and again square both sides and so on. But I have no idea how to write it.

Comment: The easiest is probably to start by showing that the algebraic numbers are closed under addition in general.

Comment: That is interesting @HenningMakholm where can I read about how to do that?

Comment: Showing the algebraic numbers are closed under addition can be an interesting exercise. I read the proof in Herstein's undergraduate algebraic text and felt satisfied, until I realized I still didn't know how to find a polynomial of which $a+b$ is a root if I had polynomials of which $a$ and $b$ are roots. So I used Herstein's proof to work out an algorithm for that.

Comment: Is it just powers of $2$? You don't need to do anything! $x = (1+2+4+...)+\sqrt{2}(1+2+4+...)=A+\sqrt{2}B$ (find the end number in each of the sums). This is a root of $(y-A-\sqrt{2}B)(y-A+\sqrt{2}B)$.

Comment: . . . . and note that $(y-A-B\sqrt2)(y-A+B\sqrt2)$ has integer coefficients: the radicals cancel when you expand it.

Comment: Yeah, the approach by orole and quasi is much simpler if your sum is only over terms of the form $\sqrt{2^k}$. I initially understood it as summing $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{2^n}$ where it was just incidental that the upper limit is a power of $2$.

Comment: Also note that in general, one can always compute sufficiently many powers of $a+b$ and use linear algebra until one finds a linear dependence relation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noted, every other element is an integer.

Each of the remaining elements can be expressed as an integer times $\sqrt{2}$, hence
$$x = a + b\sqrt{2}$$
where $a,b$ are integers.

Can you finish it?

Answer (score 4):

It is algebraic because the sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic and each number $\sqrt{2^k}$ is algebraic.

Comment: That was my immediate reaction, but in this case I think the fact that for every $n,$ the given number is $a+b\sqrt2$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ is more to the point, since you can almost instantly find the minimal polynomial.

Comment: If this is an exercise, then that approach is probably what the person who created it had in mind.